# Filter Downloads Product Name WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

These WooCommerce filter hooks :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name'
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name'
```

filter the product name on order emails sent to the customer and account > order details page but NOT the product name for **Downloads**.

Is there a hook which will also filter the **download product name** as seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This template can be overridden by copying /plugins/woocommerce/templates/order/order-downloads.php to yourtheme/woocommerce/order/order-downloads.php.

Comment: I would prefer a filter hook but if i use your method, will it also enable me to change the download product name on order emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The downloads view in the website can be overridden by copying `/plugins/woocommerce/templates/order/order-downloads.php` to `yourtheme/woocommerce/order/order-downloads.php`. – For emails modifications copy `plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-downloads.php` and override this in theme. There is no hook in the downloads table file for changing the product name.